# pass variable to replace function

Tags: javascript, replace

How can I pass variable to replace function?

```
function fname(object, object2){
    object.text.replace(/{{[^}}]+}/g,function(m,key){
        return object.replaceText[object2[m.substring(2, m.length-2)]];
    });
}
```

objects are similar:

```
object = {
    text : 'some text where I want replace {{some}} string',
    replaceText : {
        '1' : 'newText'
    }
}
object2 = { 
    some : 1
}
```

Thanks for help.

**EDIT:**
I find another way to do this, here is no problem with variable scope:

```
function fname(object1, object2){
    var reg = new RegExp(/{{[^}}]+}}/g);   
    var result;
    while((result = reg.exec(object1.text)) !== null) {
        object1.text = object1.text.replace(result[0],object1.replaceText[object2[result[0].substring(2, result[0].length-2)]]);
    }   
}
```

Thanks for everyone!

Comment: So you're writing your own really primitive version of [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)?

Comment: What do you mean by "pass variable to replace function"?  What are you trying to do?  What variable are you trying to access and where are you trying to access it?  Does this work?  Not work?  What's the problem here?

Comment: Yes, I want access object and object2

Comment: Thanks @tadman, It's good, if I not find simpler solution. I avoiding from plugins when I want only use once in my code.

Answer (score 1):

`String.prototype.replace` returns new string, so change your function like this:

```
function fname(object1, object2) {
    object1.text = object1.text.replace(/{{([^}}]+)}}/g,function(m,key){
        return object1.replaceText[object2[key]];
    });
}
```

Also change regexp to `/{{([^}}]+)}}/g` (note parenthesis). `([^}}]+)` is a matching group so you can populate `key` variable and avoid substring inconvenience.

Comment: It's right, but I can't see the object1 and object2 here, that is the problem

Comment: What do you mean? You pass them to the function.

Comment: in line where I return, there the object1 and object2 is 'undefined'